# can we make random number generator in erlang to generate different number in each iteration?

Tags: erlang

rand:uniform(2). provides 1 or 2. rand:uniform(1) gives only 1 i,e rand:uniform(N) provides random numbers between 1 and N. what about to give me 0  or 1 ? and I want to give me either 0 or 1 alternatively in each iteration i.e if we try it two times not  0 0 or 1 1 is it possible ?

Answer (score 2):

you want a random number between 0 and 1 and every time it has to be different? 01010101010... the only random number is the first one.

```
RandomNumber = rand:uniform(2)-1;
Next = case RandomNumber of 1 -> 0; _else -> 1 end.
```